# Issue about diagonal slide(or movement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, diagonal

Following this codes are just simple test to check the effect works or not before make diagonal slide effects every seconds.

To describe each of the codes, first one is just hoisted the function just like javascript does. Second one is declared the function inside of `setInterval` method. Third is declared the function outside of `setInterval`.

But all of these codes just don't work at all and I don't know why.

Have I missed something in these codes?

```js
slide()
function slide() {
  $('.box1').css({'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%)'})
}
```

```js
setInterval(function(){
$('.box1').stop().css({'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%)'})}, 2000)
```

```js
function repeat(){
  $('.box1').css({'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%)'})})
setInterval(repeat, 2000);
```

Comment: You didn't add jQuery to any of your examples. Did you add jQuery when trying these on your own?

Comment: post html also , and what you expect from this code as result ?